# I can not edit a question when there is an uncompleted edit in the queue

Tags: feature-request, bug, edits, suggested-edits

When I wish to edit [a question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397399/probability-of-winning-x-games-with-two-probabilities) (to add some additional tags) then I am missing the 'edit tags' button like I normally have. When I press the 'edit' button then I do not go the the edit dialogue but to a screen where I have to approve a pending edit.

---

The question looks like this:

- no edit-tags button
- and there is a marking '(1)' next to the edit button (probably
  referring to the review queue)

[image: question screenshot]

When I press the edit button then I end up with a screen for approving the edit. But I can not continue make edits to the tags.

[image: dialogue screen shot]

---

I consider this as a bug.

Or possibly it is made by design (to prevent errors with merging multiple edits), but it is not very useful.

If people have enough reputation points to edit questions, then why should they wait for others to approve an edit made by another person?

Does this have to do with the scoring system that approving edits is also giving points to the person that made the edit?

---

Based on the answer from Glorfindel I notice that it is made like this by design. People can edit questions with an uncompleted question by *improving* the edit. However, they must not have already have approved or rejected the edit. Then this "bug"-report would be turned into a feature request asking for the possibility to still add improvements to the edit, after already having voted on the question.

Answer (score 4):

When you review the edit, you can already choose to 'Improve' it and add the tags immediately. This will mark the suggested edit as approved and award +2 reputation to the user suggesting it.

If you feel you absolutely must edit the tags now, you could navigate to https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/397399/edit (note the ID of the post in the URL) and make the edit yourself. This will however reject the pending suggested edit.

Comment: This option to 'improve' the edit is not available anymore, probably because I already voted on it. Is it also available in the pop-up screen when I enter it via the question, or is it only available when I enter it via the review screen?

Comment: I do not absolutely need to edit the tags now, but it does make the user-experience of the website less flexible and easy when I have to hack it by using a manualy typed url to the edit screen, or when I have to wait for the edit to be completed (and possibly I will forget the question or loose interrest to improve it).

Comment: No, it's not available anymore, since you've reviewed it already. It doesn't matter if you did that in the review queue or from the question itself.